# Adding AndroidPermissions plugin to ionic project and get an error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-permissions, ionic-native

I want to add AndroidPermissions and UniqueDeviceID plugins to my project. But when I run the project I get the following error.

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at AndroidPermissions.checkPermission (index.js:182)
```

This is the details of my project:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.19
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

@angular-devkit/architect 0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core 8.3.19
@angular-devkit/schematics 8.3.19
@angular/cli 8.3.19
@angular/compiler-cli 8.2.14
@schematics/angular 8.3.19
@schematics/update 0.803.19
rxjs 5.5.11
typescript 2.6.2
webpack 3.12.0
```

C:\projeler\ohsmobile>ionic -v
5.4.6

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know how to answer this without more information, but there are some general things you could check.

1. How are you "running" the project? Since you're using Ionic Native plugins, it's important that you are testing on an emulator or on a real device. That means
   `ionic cordova build android` and opening in Android Studio or `ionic cordova run android` for a real device connected with USB.
2. Check that you have included AndroidPermissions and UniqueDeviceID as **providers** in the app.module.ts or the module.ts of the page you're trying to use it in. Example:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    providers: [AndroidPermissions, UniqueDeviceID],
    declarations: []
})
```

3. Make sure that you have run these commands from Ionic Documentation:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid
npm install @ionic-native/unique-device-id

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

4. Make sure you are importing from the correct place:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx'
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx'
```

5. Usage from Ionic Documentation:

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';


constructor(private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { }

...

this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
  result => console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission),
  err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
);

this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]);
```

Comment: "ionic cordova run android" command on the device with a USB cable I'm trying. https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-get-unique-device-id-other-uids-of-uuid-imei-imsi-iccid-and-mac-using-native-cordova-plugins/
I used this address.

Comment: Success? Error?

Comment: Error is my question.

Comment: Did you try my solution? Did it work? If not, what error message did you get? I can't help you if you don't give me any information.

Comment: I already did what you said before your first answer. Although I do as you say, I still have the problem with my question.